# Adding event to samsung calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I have an issue related to calendar. I am using ContentResolver to add event to calendar. It works pretty well on any devices accept of samsung devices. When I am trying to add event to original samsung calendar nothing happens. But when I downloaded google calendar event added properly to it. Is samsung calendar is regular calendar and how can i use it like primary calendar? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
private long insertEventTask(Activity activity, CalEvent calEvent) {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calEvent.getStartMillis());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calEvent.getEndMillis());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, calEvent.getTitle());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, calEvent.getDescription());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calEvent.getCalId());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, calEvent.getTimezone());

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
    Log.e("xxx", "uri is " + uri);
    long eventId = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    return eventId;
  }
```